# Remove From List After One Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, dynamic, arraylist

I have created a `Listbox` of foods (Apple, Banana, etc.) and have a `Javascript` running on the page that adds the selected items from the list to an `ArrayList` and as a button. The button functions such that when you click on it, the item is removed from the `ArrayList` and the button is removed as well (after a postback).

When I run this code, it adds the items to the list and creates the button, as expected. When I click on the button, however, it doesn't remove the item from the list until the page reloads a second time.

How can I have it so that the item is removed from the `ArrayList` after the click and first postback rather than after two postbacks?

```
static private ArrayList myAL { set; get; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        myAL = new ArrayList();

    Report1();

    Label1.Text = myAL.Count.ToString();
}

private void Report1()
{
    String FullFilter = ""; int FilterCount = 0;

    if (Request.Params["ListBox1Hidden"] != null && (string)Request.Params["ListBox1Hidden"] == "doubleclicked")
        myAL.Add(lstBox.SelectedItem.Text);

    myAL.Remove(Session["RemoveButton"].ToString());
    foreach (Object obj in myAL)
    {
        FilterCount++;
        if (FilterCount > 1)
            FullFilter += ", ";

        FullFilter += String.Format("'{0}'", obj);

        Button button = new Button();
        button.Text = obj.ToString();
        button.ID = "Dist" + obj.ToString();
        button.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClickOneEvent);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button);
    }

    Label1.Text += FullFilter;
}

void ButtonClickOneEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    myAL.Remove(button.Text);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use ArrayList? You should always use a strongly typed generic data structure unless you have a really compelling reason not to.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "ASP.NET C# -" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Also, did you realize that `static` fields are shared across all users of the application? That's probably not what you had in mind: if one user removes a list item, the next user will see the item as removed.

Answer (score 0):

You could save a value in viewstate indicating that the first postback has been processed.  That is probably the most straightforward approach in this case without dealing with other ways of handling static values.

Comment: I just tried to implement that, but wound up having the ViewState value still only showed in the Label after the second button click or after a refresh.

Comment: Where did you put the viewstate call?  The page_load will fire before the button event.  You may want to put the viewstate management in the PreRender event since it will fire before the page event.